# How can I get a logged user's username without the domain?

Tags: terminal, bash, script

I'm trying to write a script to automate a task that involves the logged user's username.  The problem is the username is coming up as domain/username and I just need the username.

```
LOGGEDUSER=$(stat -f "%S" /dev/console);
```

Any way to output the result and remove part of it?  This currently outputs domain/username I need to remove the `domain/`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `stat -f "%Su" /dev/console` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Local Domain

See [Get current users username in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306771/get-current-users-username-in-bash#19306837) for a range of approaches:

```
logname
```

or

```
echo $USER
```

or

```
whoami
```

or

```
id -u -n
```

## Network Domain

If you are on an (Active Directory) network domain, you can use

```
echo ${USER#*\\}
```

or

```
u=$(logname)
echo ${u#\\}
```

to just get the user name part.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Any of those methods output DOMAIN\username I need to be able to omit the DOMAIN\ part...

Comment: All of the above methods only output the username.

Comment: Do you use a local or a network login? You can easily strip the domain/ part with bash functionality actually

Comment: That's correct it's a network login that's why domain\ is being added to the username.  How can I strip it?

Comment: @WebsterMaster See updated answer.